# To show $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

> Q: $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n),\alpha>0$ and
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\leq |h|^{1+\alpha},\ h\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
> Show that $f=0$ a.e.

My attempt:
Take $\chi\in C_c^{\infty}$ s.t. $\int \chi=1$. Let $\chi_{\delta}(x):=\delta^{-n}\chi(\delta^{-1}x).$ Then we have
$$\Vert\chi_{\delta}*f-f\Vert_{L^1}\leq \int|\chi(y)|\Big(\int|f(x-\delta y)-f(x)|\,dx\Big)\,dy \leq \int|\chi(y)||\delta y|^{1+\alpha}\,dy=C\delta^{1+\alpha}$$
Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\rho\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \rho(x)\,dx=1$. Let $\rho_{\delta}(x):=\delta^{-n}\rho(\delta^{-1}x).$ Then we have $\rho_{\delta}*f(x)\to f(x)$, $a.e. x\in\mathbb R^n$ (Lebesgue point).
Note that
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\rho_{\delta}*f(x+h)-\rho_{\delta}*f(x)|\,dx&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)\rho_\delta(y)\,dy\right|\,dx\\
&\leq\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left|f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)\right|\rho_\delta(y)\,dydx\\
&\leq\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left|f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)\right|\,dx\\
&\leq |h|^{1+\alpha}.
\end{aligned}$$
Since $\rho_{\delta}*f\in C_0^\infty$, we know $\rho_{\delta}*f(x)=0\ a.e. x\in\mathbb R^n$(can be follow @ilovemath's proof), which yields $f=0 \ a.e.x\in\mathbb R^n$ .

Answer (score 0):

We have $$|\int\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx|\leqq\int |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx|\leqq h^{\alpha}$$
Now when h tends to 0, $$|\int f'(x) dx|\leqq 0$$
Which means $|f(x)|\leqq 0$.
Hence $f(x)=0$.